# Как организовать функцию php

Tags: php, yii2

Есть у меня такой php код, фреймворк yii2

```
public function getCourse($id)
    {
        $data = PriceType::find()
            ->select('course')
            ->from('price_type')
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->one();
        return $data->course;
    }
```

В этом методе sql запрос , тут цикл

```
$data = PriceType::getCourse($model->price_type_id);
                if($model->price_type_id == 1) $model->price_usd = ($model->price*$data);
                elseif ($model->price_type_id == 2) $model->price_usd = ($model->price/$data);
                elseif ($model->price_type_id == 3) $model->price_usd = ($model->price/$data);
                elseif ($model->price_type_id == 4) $model->price_usd = ($model->price/$data);
```

Если значения price_type_id равно такому то id, то выполняем такую-то операцию

if-elseif надо переписать в одну функцию. Код работает, но нужно чтобы работало в независимости от количества записей в БД.

В БД находятся курсы и названия валют. Т.е. если нужно будет добавить поле, нужно снова писать if... Как сделать по другому, по нормальному?

Comment: Что бы было по нормальному в таблицу с типами цен нужно положить операцию для перевода валют. При получении типа цены, получать из базы выражение для подготовки данных.

Comment: Каким образом это можно сделать? Хранимые процедуры ?

Comment: Раскажите какие у Вас есть типы цен и в зависимости от этого как вы готовите цены. Я предложу Вам конкретную реализацию. Я имею ввиду создать поле `operand` и допустим для типа 1 присвоить ему `*`, а для 2,3,4 `/` и по этому полю будет ясно с какой ценой что делать. Весь сыр бор только для того что бы долары переводить в локальную валюту?

Comment: У меня таблица price_type - 2 колонки 1)Валюта (USD, UAH,EUR,RUB) 2) Курс по отношению к usd (1,26,0.85,65).  Сайт объявлений , при добавлении объявления пользователь выбирает в какой валюте он хочет продавать. И вот для сортировки и фильтрации нужно иметь единую валюту. Для этого в таблице добавления объявл. добавил поле price_usd и при записи в БД пересчитываю вводимое значения по курсу usd и записываю в price_usd. Там операнд 1, только деление. Просто чего то сразу написал умножения, 10/1 = 10*1

Comment: Если Ваш `$data` это курс к долару то стандартизируйте его, что бы он указывал сколько валюты можно купить за один долар тогда всегда при установке валюты вам нужно будет делить а при получении умножать в не зависимости от валюты. А также сделать отдельный крон который раз в 10мин. будет обновлять курсы.

Comment: не решает вопроса, но на будущее, используйте switch